# cs50 resize compiles, but 'Image does not match expected image'

Tags: c, resize, cs50

I'm currently working on the resize (more comfortable) in C (from CS50).
Goal: by getting a float, inputfile and outputfile. Resize the inputfile and create a new outputfile.

My code compiles, but during the check I get the error : Image does not match expected image.

So my formulas for the new image sizes could be wrong:

```
//new
int padding_new =  (4 - (width_new * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

// change in image size
bi.biSizeImage = height_new * ((width_new * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) + padding_new);
```

Or there is something wrong when changing it:

```
 // iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0; i < height_new; i++)
{
    // Write each line factor-times
    for (int l = 0; l < f; l++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < width_new; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, input);

            for (int m = 0; m < f; m++)
            {
                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, resized);
            }
        }
        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(input, padding_new, SEEK_CUR);

        // then add it back (to demonstrate how)
        for (int k = 0; k < padding_new; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, resized);
        }

        fseek(input, -(width_old * 3 + padding_old), SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fseek(input, width_old * 3 + padding_old, SEEK_CUR);
```

I hope this is understandable and I hope someone can help me!

Comment: what check/how are you checking? If you're resizing the image then they're going to be different and I would expect them not to match.

Comment: I'm checking with check50 (inbuilt function for cs50 to check your code)

The check gives:

:(resize.c compiles.
:( doesn't resize 3x3-pixel BMP when n is 1,
    resized image does not match expected image.
:( resizes 18x18-pixel BMP to 9x9 correctly when f is 0.5,
    resized image does not match expected image.

So there needs to be something wrong in the code

Comment: When `f` is `0.5` you go through the loop only once, so basically you read/write the same thing. If you do change the height, that needs to be reflected in bitmap header if there is any. Is this homework? You should be using an image library to resize images.

Comment: Yea this is homework. I will look at the bitmap header. Thank you!